# Bootstrap: Accomplish left-, right-margins on form-elements when size becomes extra-small?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made this form which behaves and looks decent on all size larger the xs (extra small).

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.row:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form action="" method="GET" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
          <legend>Form title</legend>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-2">Your First Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="Please enter your first name.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-2">Your Last Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Please enter your last name.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2">Your Email: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email adresse.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2">Your Phone Number: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when the display becomes extra small then the inputs and labels stretch until the edges of the browser window.

[image: On a small scaled window.]

I would like to have a small margin on the left and on the right.

I'm I doing something wrong?

Is there are way to fix this issue with just bootstrap?
Or do I have to add some additional CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution. Actually a blunder.
Just change the `class="form-horizontal"` to `class="form-vertical"` ....

DEMO:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form action="" method="GET" role="form" class="form-vertical">
        <div class="row">
          <legend>Form title</legend>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-2">Your First Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="Please enter your first name.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name" class="col-sm-2">Your Last Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name" placeholder="Please enter your last name.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2">Your Email: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email adresse.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2">Your Phone Number: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <button type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```